# Cyclic subgroup of ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to prove the following fact about the group ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$:

> If $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of order $q^2-1$ then it contains the center of ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Any hint to prove this?

(This I saw as a remark in a book on group theory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is easy: let $A$ be an element of order $q^2-1$ in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$. The minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ of $A$ should be of degree $2$ and irreducible, otherwise it can be triangularized and order of $A$ does not divide upper triangular matrix subgroup.

Thus if $\alpha$ is a root of $m_A(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}\setminus \mathbb{F}_q$ then $\alpha^q$ is also a root, and $\alpha\neq \alpha^q$ (since $\alpha\notin\mathbb{F}_q$).

Then ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ can be considered as subgroup of ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$, and $A$ can be diagonalized in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$, i .e. $PAP^{-1}=$ diag$(\alpha,\alpha^q)$.

Then $q+1$-th power of $PAP^{-1}$ is scalar  matrix diag$(\alpha^{q+1},\alpha^{q+1})$ in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ whose order is $q-1$. But the only scalar matrices of order $q-1$ in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ are scalars in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q})$.

Thus $q+1$-th power of $A$ is a scalar matrix in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ of order $q-1$. Thus, 
$$\langle A\rangle \supseteq \langle A^{q+1}\rangle=Z({\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{q}))$$